# Cloudfront distribution having multiple domains

Tags: node.js, aws, react, graphql

I am developing a multi-tenant project that will be a kind of micro "ecommerce" and therefore customers will be able to create their own stores and will be able to choose between creating a subdomain or using their own domain. This whole process needs to be "whitelabel". I will only use AWS. It will be a kind of shopify.

The project will have an application made in wordpress that will be a landing page to talk about the base product.

The project will have several micro apis exposed on separate endpoints but which will be consumed by the graphql federation (a kind of BFF) and therefore there will only be a single accessible endpoint for react-apps to consume.

In addition to the api, I need to create some react-apps (I will use the concept of micro frontends) and therefore I will need:

- 1 application for the seller to create an account, create and list their stores
- 1 application for the seller to manage a specific store
- 1 application for the seller to sell the products and show the catalog
- 1 application for administrators to approve stores and do other things

The big challenge is to manage the routes and save the routing and so I thought about the following:

example.com -> wordpress landing page
example.com/seller -> the seller can create an account and see the listing of their stores

store.example.com or customdomain.com -> store that shows a seller's products
store.example.com/backoffice or customdomain.com/backoffice -> customized subdomain for the seller to manage a specific store

Since I need the domains / subdomains to be customized to be whitelabel, I also need the api to be accessible at example.com/graphql or store.example.com/graphql or customdomain.com/graphql

I would like to know how can I do this using AWS? After some investigation I noticed that the cloudfront can do this and also use route53 to point the domains / subdomains for distribution on the cloudfront, but to be honest, I need some advice.

Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

Yes,approved to that idea of yours!
And in addition to that ,why still using an alias?Let's straight to the real name of the account owner.
It's most favorable for them the provided securities,for their selves otherwise for their account assets also.
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Hiding for there profile is not 100 percent secure.And I don't want to say that the management may have a chance to control with your assets to the bypass the account owner.